# manually set latitude, longitude range for geoviews

Tags: python, holoviews, geoviews

I am plotting data using the [GeoViews](http://geoviews.org/index.html) [QuadMesh](http://holoviews.org/Reference_Manual/holoviews.element.htm) element.  I can't find a way to expand the geographic region of my plot beyond a tiny bit past the edges of my data.  I would like to provide a little more context (coastlines, etc) by showing the area bounded by [34, 36] N latitude and [30.5, 32.5] E longitude.  Here's my code (from a Jupyter notebook):

```
import xarray as xr
import numpy as np
import holoviews as hv
from holoviews import opts
import geoviews as gv
import geoviews.feature as gf
from cartopy import crs as ccrs

gv.extension('matplotlib', 'bokeh')

dummy_data = np.arange(100).reshape((10, 10))
dummy_lats = np.tile(np.arange(0, 90, 9), (10, 1))
dummy_lons = np.transpose(dummy_lats)

dummy2d = xr.Dataset(data_vars={'data': (['x', 'y'], dummy_data)},
                     coords={'lat2d': (['x', 'y'], dummy_lats),
                             'lon2d': (['x', 'y'], dummy_lons)})

gf.ocean * gf.land  * gv.Dataset(dummy2d.data).to(gv.QuadMesh)
```

I have tried:

```
gf.ocean * gf.land  * gv.Dataset(dummy2d.data).to(gv.QuadMesh, extent=(34, 30.5, 36, 32.5))
```

which issues a warning `WARNING:param.QuadMesh05440: Setting non-parameter attribute extent=(34, 30.5, 36, 32.5) using a mechanism intended only for parameters`  without changing the plot.

I also tried

```
img = gf.ocean * gf.land  * gv.Dataset(dummy2d.data).to(gv.QuadMesh)
img.redim.range(Latitude=(34, 36), Longitude=(30.5, 32.5))
```

This has no discernible effect.